# Facebook Activity Feed Disappears after 1 minute

Tags: facebook, android-activity, feed

Hopefully this is simple. The new activity feed is disappearing on me in every browser on MAC, and all but IE on the PC. See Here:

http://www.montanafolkfestival.com

half way down the page under "What's Hot" ("get social" is working fine). Literally 45 seconds and it disappears. Seems like it's a feed issue from Facebook. Anyone else seen this? Thoughts on how to fix?

thanks,
kevin

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like the users fault.  It is also happening on the page with the sample code provided by Facebook:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/activity/

Comment: Ah yes, there's an open bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/500201816697073